# SwiftUI: data identifier stability and uniqueness

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

At minute 33:00 of [Demystify SwiftUI WWDC21 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/), Raj talked about the importance of using a stable & unique identifier for the data model that will be rendered in a SwiftUI view, so using something like this is not recommended:

[image]

but something like this is a best practice:

[image]

I have regular data model structs (not persisted to disk or CoreData) that I need to render their data in SwiftUI views, how to create unique and stable IDs for those models ?

Comment: You only want to use explicit identity, if the _structural_ identity is ambiguous or not sufficient. For example in lists, where you have many RowViews, each one associated to a certain model value. This requires the RowViews to have an explicit id to disambiguate them from each other and detect changes when you change the list items. This is necessary to make SwiftUI recognise insertion, deletions, movement, etc. so that it can render animation for the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clearly mentioned  in the WWDC video but an unique identifier is supposed to be a **constant**.

```
struct Pet : Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
}
```

If the struct is being created from JSON with `Decodable` just add `CodingKeys` to exclude the identifier

```
struct Pet : Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name : String

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case name }
}
```

Anyway use constants whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a stored property instead of computed property.

as mention in [docs.swift.org](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html)

> computed properties, which don’t actually store a value. Instead, they provide a getter and an optional setter to retrieve and set other properties and values indirectly.

It means when using computed properties as their value change each time you are calling them.

So use stored property like this

```
struct Model {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
}
```

As the computed property is that runs code again and give you to new result.