SwiftUI list animation changing the way it animates when I replace dummy data with real data?
I have an animation I made for a game totals list that saves the previous result and on the next time the view opens floats the users result view to the new position from the old ranking position. I built it with dummy data in a simple test app, but when I try to change the method to handle the data dynamically from a server response; the way it animates changes drastically.
How can I stop this from happening?
List View
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var vm = DataHandler()
    
    @State private var oldPositionX: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var oldPositionY: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var newPositionX: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var newPositionY: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var offsetValueX = 0.0
    @State private var offsetValueY = 0.0
    @State private var objectAtNewPosition: CompetitionResult? = nil
    @State private var showNewData = false
    @State private var isAnimating = false
    
    var data: [CompetitionResult] {
        if showNewData {
            return  vm.newData
        }
        return vm.oldData
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(data) { item in
                if !showNewData {
                    // OLD DATA
                    ListCell(item: item)
                        .overlay(
                            GeometryReader{ geo in
                                Color.clear
                                    .onAppear {
                                        setRanks(item: item, geo: geo)
                                    }
                            }
                        )
                        .padding(.horizontal, isAnimating ? 8 : 0)
                        .padding(.vertical, isAnimating ? 2 : 0)
                        .background(item.uuid == vm.userUuid && isAnimating ? Color.blue : Color.clear)
                        .foregroundStyle(item.uuid == vm.userUuid ? Color.white : Color.black)
                        .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: item.uuid == vm.userUuid && isAnimating ? 8 : 0))
                        .offset(x: setXOffset(item), y: setYOffset(item))
                        .opacity(setOpacity(item))
                } else {
                    // NEW DATA
                    ListCell(item: item)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear() {
            startAnimation()
        }
    }
}

// CELL 
struct ListCell: View {
    let item: CompetitionResult
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("\(item.ranking)")
                Text(item.name)
                Spacer()
                Text("\(item.total)")
            }
            Divider()
        }
    }
}


View Methods
extension ContentView {
    // START ---- Animation
    private func startAnimation() {
        isAnimating = true
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4.5) {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.5)) {
                showNewData = true
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 3.5)) {
                offsetValueX = newPositionX - oldPositionX
                offsetValueY = newPositionY - oldPositionY
                isAnimating = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    // SET OPACITY ---
    private func setOpacity(_ item: CompetitionResult) -> CGFloat {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
            if let object = objectAtNewPosition {
                if item.ranking == object.ranking && !isAnimating {
                    return 0
                }
                return 1
            }
            return 1
        }
    }
    
    
    // SET OFFSETS ---
    private func setXOffset(_ item: CompetitionResult) -> CGFloat {
        if item.ranking == vm.oldRank {
            return offsetValueX
        }
        return 0
    }
    
    private func setYOffset(_ item: CompetitionResult) -> CGFloat {
        if item.ranking == vm.oldRank {
            return offsetValueY
        }
        return 0
    }
    
    
    // SET RANKS ---
    private func setRanks(item: CompetitionResult, geo: GeometryProxy) {
        getOldRank(vm.oldRank, item: item, geo: geo)
        getNewRank(vm.newRank, item: item, geo: geo)
    }
    
    
    private func getOldRank(_ oldRank: Int, item: CompetitionResult, geo: GeometryProxy) {
        if item.ranking == oldRank {
            oldPositionX = geo.frame(in: .global).midX
            oldPositionY = geo.frame(in: .global).midY
        }
    }
    
    private func getNewRank(_ newRank: Int, item: CompetitionResult, geo: GeometryProxy) {
        if item.ranking == newRank {
            newPositionX = geo.frame(in: .global).midX
            newPositionY = geo.frame(in: .global).midY
            self.objectAtNewPosition = item
        }
    }
}

Model & View Model
import SwiftUI

public struct CompetitionResult: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    public var id: String { uuid }
    public let uuid: String
    public let name: String
    public var total: Float
    public var ranking: Int
    public let date: String
    
    public init(uuid: String, name: String, total: Float, ranking: Int, date: String) {
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.name = name
        self.total = total
        self.ranking = ranking
        self.date = date
    }
}

class DataHandler: ObservableObject {
    
    let userUuid: String
    @Published var oldData: [CompetitionResult] = []
    @Published var newData: [CompetitionResult] = []
    @Published var oldRank = 7
    @Published var newRank = 3
    
   
    init(uuid: String = "SET_TO_USER_UUID") {
        self.userUuid = uuid
         setUpAnimation()
    }
    
    func setUpAnimation() {
        if let pastResult = getOldRank() {
            let results = setResultData(pastResult, results: getData())
            self.oldRank = pastResult.ranking
            self.newRank = results.2
            self.oldData = results.0
            self.newData = results.1
        }
    }
    
    
    // Need to save rank on get results fetch, then next time get previous result/rank from User Defaults, set old data with old result / remove old result from old data. New Data will be current fetch. SET old rank and new rank properties
    private func setResultData(_ previousResult: CompetitionResult, results: [CompetitionResult]) -> ([CompetitionResult], [CompetitionResult], Int) {
        
        //MARK: --- ISSUE ----
        
        //MARK: IF I use the below code the animation style changes
//        var oldResults = results
//        oldResults.removeAll(where: {$0.uuid == previousResult.uuid})
//        oldResults.insert(previousResult, at: previousResult.ranking - 1)
        
        //MARK: THIS WORKS
        let oldResults: [CompetitionResult] = [
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "1", name: "One", total: 100, ranking: 1, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "2", name: "Two", total: 99, ranking: 2, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "3", name: "Three", total: 98, ranking: 3, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "4", name: "Four", total: 97, ranking: 4, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "5", name: "Five", total: 96, ranking: 5, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "6", name: "Six", total: 95, ranking: 6, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "SET_TO_USER_UUID", name: "Seven", total: 94, ranking: 7, date: ""), // OLD Rank
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "8", name: "Eight", total: 93, ranking: 8, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "9", name: "Nine", total: 92, ranking: 9, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "10", name: "Ten", total: 91, ranking: 10, date: ""),
        ]
        
        print(oldResults)
        // (Old Data, New Data, Current Rank
        return (oldResults, results, results.filter {$0.uuid == previousResult.uuid}.first?.ranking ?? 0)
    }
    
    
    // GET OLD Rank from User Defaults
    private func getOldRank() -> CompetitionResult? {
        CompetitionResult(uuid: "SET_TO_USER_UUID", name: "Seven", total: 94, ranking: 7, date: "") // OLD Rank
    }
    
    private func getData() -> [CompetitionResult] {
        let data: [CompetitionResult] = [
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "1", name: "One", total: 100, ranking: 1, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "2", name: "Two", total: 99, ranking: 2, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "SET_TO_USER_UUID", name: "Seven", total: 94, ranking: 3, date: ""), // NEW Rank - Current Rank
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "3", name: "Three", total: 98, ranking: 4, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "4", name: "Four", total: 97, ranking: 5, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "5", name: "Five", total: 96, ranking: 6, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "6", name: "Six", total: 95, ranking: 7, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "8", name: "Eight", total: 93, ranking: 8, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "9", name: "Nine", total: 92, ranking: 9, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "10", name: "Ten", total: 91, ranking: 10, date: ""),
        ]
        return data
    }
}

The issue is when I change how the data is mutated in this method:
    private func setResultData(_ previousResult: CompetitionResult, results: [CompetitionResult]) -> ([CompetitionResult], [CompetitionResult], Int) {
        
        //MARK: --- ISSUE ----
        
        //MARK: IF I use the below code the animation style changes
//        var oldResults = results
//        oldResults.removeAll(where: {$0.uuid == previousResult.uuid})
//        oldResults.insert(previousResult, at: previousResult.ranking - 1)
        
        //MARK: THIS WORKS
        let oldResults: [CompetitionResult] = [
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "1", name: "One", total: 100, ranking: 1, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "2", name: "Two", total: 99, ranking: 2, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "3", name: "Three", total: 98, ranking: 3, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "4", name: "Four", total: 97, ranking: 4, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "5", name: "Five", total: 96, ranking: 5, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "6", name: "Six", total: 95, ranking: 6, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "SET_TO_USER_UUID", name: "Seven", total: 94, ranking: 7, date: ""), // OLD Rank
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "8", name: "Eight", total: 93, ranking: 8, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "9", name: "Nine", total: 92, ranking: 9, date: ""),
            CompetitionResult(uuid: "10", name: "Ten", total: 91, ranking: 10, date: ""),
        ]
        
        print(oldResults)
        // (Old Data, New Data, Current Rank
        return (oldResults, results, results.filter {$0.uuid == previousResult.uuid}.first?.ranking ?? 0)
    }

Working animation

NOT Working animation

UPDATE
If I edit the method by removing this line, it works correctly again:
        var oldResults = results
//        oldResults.removeAll(where: {$0.uuid == previousResult.uuid})
        oldResults.insert(previousResult, at: previousResult.ranking - 1)


Can you elaborate or show an example please?

@MojtabaHosseini I believe this is what you are referring too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68631806/swiftui-data-identifier-stability-and-uniqueness My uuid is a constant returned from the server?

@MojtabaHosseini I changed the id property to this: public let id: String = UUID().uuidString but it changed nothing

I think you're confused. Yes, it's a constant id. Always the same. The uuid and id are always "SET_TO_USER_UUID"

I removed the conformance to Identifiable and the id entirely. The uuid is hard coded to "SET_TO_USER_UUID" for testing. This changed nothing. Thanks for your attempts @MojtabaHosseini
